# Is $g(t)$ a solution to the initial value problem $\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} y' = f(t,y(t)) \\ y(t_0)=y_0 \end{array} \right.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, uniform-convergence, initial-value-problems

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open. Consider the initial value problem

$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
y' = f(t,y(t)) \\
y(t_0)=y_0
\end{array}
\right.$

where $t_0=[a,b]$ and $f\in C(J\times E, \mathbb{R}^n) $. Suppose that the Picard iteration $\{g_n(t)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent to a function $g(t)$ in $J$.

Do $g(t)$ have to be a solution to the previous problem?

I think that it does, however I do not know what arguments I can give. I am suppose to know it through Cauchy-Lipstchitz's and Peano's theorems. \
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $g_n(t)$ is defined as
$$g_{n+1}=y_0+\int_{t_0}^t f(s,g_{n}(s))\mathop{ds}$$
where $g_0(t)= y_0$. Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ in the expression above yields
$$\begin{align*}
g(t)&= y_0 +\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{t_0}^tf(s,g_n(s))\mathop{ds}\\
&=y_0 +\int_{t_0}^t f(s, \lim_{n\to \infty} g_n(s))\mathop{ds}\\
&= y_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s, g(s)) \mathop{ds}
&= 
\end{align*}$$
where we have used the hypothesis that $g_n(t)$ converges uniformly to $g(t)$ to justify the exchange between the limit and the integral, and the fact that $f$ is continuous to justify that $\lim f(s, g_n)= f(s, \lim g_n)$. Now, to see that $g(t)$ is indeed a solution to the IVP just differentiate both sides on the equality above and see what happens when plugging $t_0$.